# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException when using http2

Tags: jsf, wildfly, http2

I have an jsf app and everything works fine, but when I'm turning on http2 in my wildfly:

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="qsSSLContext" enable-http2="false"/>
```

I got a lot of errors like this:

```
2020-04-30 13:08:55,275 ERROR [io.undertow] (default task-11) UT005085: Connection io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2ServerConnection@3dfd4981 for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /# request {cache-control=[max-age=0], :authority=[localhost:8443], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], sec-fetch-user=[?1], :scheme=[https], sec-fetch-site=[none], cookie=[JSESSIONID=EVww3EEPs_jrWhneTnQrNlv82L5odSoGuzfH699Z], Referer=[https://localhost:8443/], Host=[localhost:8443], accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.9,lv-LV;q=0.8,lv;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5], sec-fetch-mode=[navigate], :path=[/#], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36], sec-fetch-dest=[document], :method=[GET], upgrade-insecure-requests=[1]} response {Expires=[Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=EVww3EEPs_jrWhneTnQrNlv82L5odSoGuzfH699Z.desktop-dcuvc4o; path=/confero-portal], Pragma=[no-cache], Date=[Thu, 30 Apr 2020 10:08:55 GMT], :status=[404], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=2500], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[68]}} was not closed cleanly, forcibly closing connection

2020-04-30 13:08:56,076 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-9) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, theme.css, from library, primefaces-bootstrap.
2020-04-30 13:08:56,076 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-9) : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:238)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:574)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:150)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at ...
```

Could you please explain me, why http2 is not working with jsf and wildfly?

Comment: I see an 'error' that a client does not correctly close a connection (jsf cannot help it) and I see two warnings that a resource is not loaded. There is an explanation for all this, but what is it that is effectively 'not working' (not really a developer way of explaining things).  Oh and [ask] states you to search... I put your title in a [search engine and added 'jsf'](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=jsf++java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException+when+using+http2)... Did you do this and read the results?

Comment: Strange question. You didn't enable HTTP2 at all: `enable-http2="false"`.

Comment: @BalusC: Good catch, but I suspect a copy/paste error of a diferent attempt. Still I do not know of an existing Q/A in SO that addresses this. It is sort of fragmented to on other sites... And I personally honestly would not know the real answer... https://developer.jboss.org/thread/280291 https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=178484#p178484 https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278505

Comment: Yeap copy/paste from different attempt and yes I searched a lot of results before asked here...